# Play test-only doesn't ignore tests

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a play application and I need to ignore my functional tests when I compile and build, then later run only the integration tests.

This is my test code:

**ApplicationSpec.scala**

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ApplicationSpec extends Specification {

   "Application" should {
      "send 404 on a bad request" in new WithApplication {
         route(FakeRequest(GET, "/boum")) must beNone
   }

}
```

**IntegrationSpec.scala**

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class IntegrationSpec extends Specification {

    "Application" should {
       "work from within a browser" in {
           running(TestServer(9000), FIREFOX) { browser =>
               browser.goTo("http://localhost:9000/app")
               browser.pageSource must contain("Your new application is ready.")
           }
       }
    } section "integration"
}
```

The docs tells me I can use something like this from the command line:

`play "test-only -- exclude integration"`

The only problem is that this doesn't actually exclude any tests and my integration tests invoke firefox and start running. What am I doing wrong? How can I exclude the integration tests and then later run them by themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sbt's [Testing documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing) describes several ways to define separate test configurations.

For instance, the [Additional test configurations with shared sources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing#additional-test-configurations-with-shared-sources) example could be used in this situation:

> In this approach, the sources are compiled together using the same classpath and are packaged together. However, different tests are run depending on the configuration.

In a default Play Framework 2.2.2 application created with `play new`, add a file named `project/Build.scala` with this content:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object B extends Build {
  lazy val root =
    Project("root", file("."))
      .configs(FunTest)
      .settings(inConfig(FunTest)(Defaults.testTasks) : _*)
      .settings(
        libraryDependencies += specs,
        testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Filter(unitFilter)),
        testOptions in FunTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(itFilter))
      )

  def itFilter(name: String): Boolean = (name endsWith "IntegrationSpec")
  def unitFilter(name: String): Boolean = (name endsWith "Spec") && !itFilter(name)

  lazy val FunTest = config("fun") extend(Test)
  lazy val specs = "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.0" % "test"
}
```

To run standard unit tests:

```
$ sbt test
```

Which produces:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/fernando/work/scratch/so23160453/project
[info] Set current project to so23160453 (in build file:/home/fernando/work/scratch/so23160453/)
[info] ApplicationSpec
[info] Application should
[info] + send 404 on a bad request
[info] + render the index page
[info] Total for specification ApplicationSpec
[info] Finished in 974 ms
[info] 2 examples, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] Passed: Total 2, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 2
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed Apr 22, 2014 12:42:37 PM
```

To run tests for the added configuration (here, "fun"), prefix it with the configuration name:

```
$ sbt fun:test
```

Which produces:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/fernando/work/scratch/so23160453/project
[info] Set current project to so23160453 (in build file:/home/fernando/work/scratch/so23160453/)
[info] IntegrationSpec
[info] Application should
[info] + work from within a browser
[info] Total for specification IntegrationSpec
[info] Finished in 0 ms
[info] 1 example, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
[success] Total time: 6 s, completed Apr 22, 2014 12:43:17 PM
```

You can also test only a particular class, like this:

```
$ sbt "fun:testOnly IntegrationSpec"
```

See [this example](https://github.com/fernandoacorreia/so23160453) in GitHub.

Comment: I've seen this documentation, but I don't see how it applies. This is a standard play 2 app, started with `play new myApp`. I don't have an explicit Build anywhere. I do have a build.sbt file, but it has a different syntax and I'm not sure I can define functions in it. It looks like play has a layer on top of sbt. I'm also not sure what console you're implying with `>`. I'm looking for the correct syntax to kick off this process from the shell so I can integrate it with CI.

Comment: @usmcs The example's syntax is for a `Build.scala` build definition file. By default, Play applications have a `build.sbt` file. The `Build.scala` settings could be converted to `build.sbt` format but I don't know how to do that in this case. But that's not a problem because both settings interoperate [as explained here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html). I've updated the answer and created an example in GitHub. The instructions use `sbt` instead of `play` because `play` is just a wrapper and is being deprecated.